# how to change selected value in html using c#?

Tags: c#, html, combobox, webclient

im trying to get some datas from a webpage. im writing code in c# .net. the webpage has a dropdown list (or combobox) like i showed below. data changes according to selected dropdown list item but url does not change. my question is how can my code changes selected values and get datas from webpage? i parsed and got for only one of items like that:

```
        **WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string kaynak = wc.DownloadString("http://www.diyanet.gov.tr/");
        string imsak = "spImsak";
        int imindex = kaynak.IndexOf(imsak);
        imindex += 9;
        System.Console.WriteLine(kaynak.Substring(imindex, 5));**
```

< span id="spImsak">02:44< /span >

i downloaded html code of webpage as a string. searched "spImsak". finally i got "02:44" as a string. and i wanna do it for all combobox items. can you give me any advice?

sample webpage : http://www.diyanet.gov.tr/

red ones are comboboxes. yellow one is data that i wanna get.

[image]

Comment: For reading fragments of an html string, look into HtmlAgilityPack. Then you can find that span by it's id.

Comment: When you are downloading an HTML page this way, you get a fresh copy from the server, not whatever is in *your* browser. Plus it's just a string that doesn't know anything about comboboxes etc.

Comment: @HansKesting my company doesn't want to use third part libraries.

Comment: @HansKesting i know that i got a string. do u have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have followed up webpage's network and saw that when i click any dropdown list element, webpage runs a web service with parameters. i explain how to applied that to my question.

[web service and parameters image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqELC.png)

all i need send a POST request this web service with these parameters and got string (json). i did that following c# code.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            int turn;
            byte[] response;
            string result;
            /* gets response for 81 city */
            for (turn = 500; turn < 581; ++turn)
            {

                response =
                client.UploadValues("http://diyanet.gov.tr/PrayerTime/MainPrayerTimesSet", new NameValueCollection()
                {
                    { "countryName", "2" },
                    { "name", turn.ToString() }
                });
                /* without sleep, web service does not response successive requests */
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);

                /* turns incoming byte[] -> string */ 
                result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
```